# Symfony - I need to insert or update a record in database

Tags: database, symfony1, insert, doctrine

The primary key is Id, but i want to check if already exists a record in db with same acronym, and if not, insert a new one, if exists, I need to do an update. I wrote this code, but it doesn't work. I receive this message from symfony "Integrity violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '180' for key 'PRIMARY'"

```
$id = Doctrine_Core::getTable('college')->findBy('acronym', 'PMM')->getFirst()->getId();
$college = new college();
$college->setId($id);
$college->setAcronym('PMM');
$college->setName('Paulo Miguel Mar');
$college->setUrl('www.pmm.com');
$college->save();
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks.
Alexandre Sousa

---

I've tried the replace() solution, but I have some problems because I want to keep my id field. So I wanna do an update and not a replace.

I think save() should works, cause I read somewhere that this function is smart enough to do an update or insert. I still get this message: "Integrity violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '180' for key 'PRIMARY"

Anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is dead simple, just use `replace()`:

```
$college = new college();
$college
  ->setAcronym('PMM')
  ->setName('Paulo Miguel Mar')
  ->setUrl('www.pmm.com')
  ->replace()
```

This will work if and only if you have specified acronym as unique, of course.